# undefined reference to `main' - but main function included

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, program-entry-point, undefined-reference

I am getting the following error when trying to compile my code:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using the following command:

```
g++ detectTemplatePoints.cpp -o SURF_TemplatePoints `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

From what I can find online this seems to happen when you do not have a `main` entry point included but I do have that,  my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
using namespace cv;

void readme();
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if( argc != 2 ) {
    readme(); return -1; 
  }
  Mat img_1 = imread( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
  if( !img_1.data ) { 
    std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; 
  }
  int minHessian = 400;
  SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
  detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
  Mat img_keypoints_1;
  drawKeypoints( img_1, keypoints_1, img_keypoints_1, Scalar::all(-1), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );
  imshow("Keypoints 1", img_keypoints_1 );
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
void readme() {
  std::cout << " Usage: ./detectTemplatePoints <img1>" << std::endl;
}
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: This can't be your complete code, there is something more, and the problem is probably in there (like a macro going wild)

Comment: What is the purpose of return -1 on the fourth line?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I have included my full code in the question now.

Comment: @DeepikaSethi No doubt a typo, because anything outside of the range `[0...255]` won't get correctly transferred.

Comment: Eliminate unnecessary unknowns. Create a C++ source file with an empty `main` function and compile and link it into an executable. Then add things one by one: print "hello world", add cflags,  add libs, add content in main... Look where the process breaks down.

Comment: @Colin747: That full code works fine here, there must be something else you did that you didnt tell us.

Comment: Would it be a problem with command or did you try the same command that I'm using?

Comment: What does `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` output?

Comment: Does the tutorial from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html compile as-is?

Comment: Yes, I've two other examples that all compile.

Comment: For some reason if I take the same file and move it to a different directory it is compiling fine...

Comment: "move it to a different directory"? As in, *this* example you posted works on a directory but not on another one?

Comment: Try using -c while compiling...

Comment: @DeepikaSethi `-c` means "don't link". It **won't** have the intended result.

Comment: @luiscubal yes I moved it up a single directory and it compiled successfully, same code and command

Comment: @Colin747 Hmm... Sorry if this one is too obvious, but I know it has happened to me before so I'll ask it anyway. Is there any chance you've been editing the wrong file? That is, the file on the "bad directory" is actually an old version that doesn't have a main method and you've been accidentally editing another file thinking it was `detectTemplatePoints.cpp` when it wasn't?

Comment: Tbh @luiscubal I've a bad feeling that could have been what was happening...sorry for wasting everyones time if that was the case

Comment: I hate it when that happens. I hate it worse when I have an SO question out on it. :(

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says: you have no `main` function.  They have to have one of the following signatures:

```
int main()
```

or

```
int main(int, char**)
```

Comment: I have a `main` function declared on the second line?

Comment: added explanation as to why you don't have it to comment

Comment: @PaulEvans His code seems to have the correct main signature now and the error persists so that can't be the cause.

Comment: @luiscubal then it's the compile command

Comment: @PaulEvans: It isn't, it is working fine with that compile command for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `g++ detectTemplatePoints.cpp -o SURF_TemplatePoints $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` ) in order to link opencv libraries.
Also, you haven't shown us the libraries you are including.
I can get it compiled so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void readme();

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  if( argc != 2 ) {
    readme(); return -1; 
  }
  Mat img_1 = imread( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
  if( !img_1.data ) { 
    std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; 
  }
  int minHessian = 400;
  SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
  detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
  Mat img_keypoints_1;
  drawKeypoints( img_1, keypoints_1, img_keypoints_1, Scalar::all(-1), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );
  imshow("Keypoints 1", img_keypoints_1 );
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
void readme() {
  std::cout << " Usage: ./detectTemplatePoints <img1>" << std::endl;
}
```